# modernizr - i do not see ANY classes

Tags: modernizr

i have a test website here with SVG images and want to create fallbacks with "modernizr". it loads the script but adds no classes to "html" like here:

[image]

in my case there is no class. here is my test website:
http://herrfischerhamburg.de/_jsfiddle/mnizr/

as you can see there's only "".

am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

got it - under the "extra" tab on the modernizr build site i had to tick "add css classes" ...